# iPhone app upgrade to a new version failure

Tags: iphone, upgrade, store

I am going add a new version for my app. However,  when I finished the development with a new xcode project and try to update from the old version with the same Bundle identifier, error exists and the new version can't not be launched successfully and crash every time.

In the new project, all the classes are new created and the implementation is different. Also, the class name of appDelegate is different.

How can I make a success update in my case?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the same **Bundle Identifier** as an existing app currently installed on your device. Classes and Delegates have nothing to do with your issue. You need to make sure your new app does not contain the same bundle id as any other apps.

```
Old Version: com.yourcompany.yourapp
New Version: com.yourcompany.yourapptaketwo
```

These are Bundle ID's and are unique for each app, they cannot be the same. If you are updating an existing app, try removing the old one from the device first.

Comment: can you help me for my question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7976750/points-to-note-for-future-upgrade-of-app-without-new-install-in-iphone