# Points to note for Future upgrade of App without new install in iPhone?

Tags: ios, iphone

What are the points to keep in mind for upgradation of app?

How the upgradation is done in device? I mean what are the changes done in filesystem of device?

If I am involving new View in my app, then how can I be able to add in my existing app in Device. Will this be automatically done by AppStore??

I have reviewed the previous post but not getting clear idea of how to program the app...

Please help me in this issue...

**EDIT** (for simple idea)

Suppose i have distributed an app in appStore. Now I found new feature to be included. So I have added in my app and now what should i have to do so that all my current users of app will be updated with my new feature??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have added new features to your app, increase the version number and re-release it to the app store. This will appear as an update in the app store to all your users. If they then download it, the application will be replaced on their device with your new version. The documents and preferences will remain as they were before.

Answer (score 0):

Cant understand your question clearly.
DO you whant to update some data in your application,  without registrating new app version in iTunes, correct?
You can store datestamp of your current version ias a file in app folder, then check out if any updates, download them and replace old data with new:

```
NSString *s = @"datestamp here"
    NSData* d = [s dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    [d writeToFile:[NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"datestamp"] atomically:YES];
```

to load file:

```
NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"datestamp"]];
    NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

Comment: Suppose i have distributed an app in appStore. Now I found new feature to be included. So I have added in my app and now what should i have to do so that all my current users of app will be updated with my new feature??

Comment: go to iTunes connect, find your application in your profile, somewhere in it's settings you can just annonce new version. then, upload your new binary to app store, just like you did when distributed it 1st time. After it will be appruved by apple,  all your users will notifyed by arr store about new version. If they pass it, app automatically updates, all in-app saved data will NOT deleted